# Pdf viewer Copy and paste snapshots

Tags: installation, pdf

I want to get a snapshot copy and paste from pdf viewer. But I couldnt do it. Then I tried downlaod acrobat and got downlaoded file AdbeRdr9.5.5-1_i486linux_enu.bin but I couldnt run it. Please help

Comment: Please edit you question with 1. What happened when you tried to copy-paste. 2. *why* you couldn't install it

Answer (score 5):

Just press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Print Screen</kbd> and hold them while with your mouse select the rectangle of your screen you want to print.

Answer (score 3):

If, by "snapshot copy and paste" you mean selecting a rectangular region and copying it, you can use the Screenshot program to do exactly that. Just search "Screenshot" from the dash.

Normally, when you select a rectangular region with a .pdf reader, it will copy the true number of pixels. So make sure it is zoomed in to precisely 100% when using Screenshot to do this.